# Mass email inbox creation API

Tags: email, nodemailer, mass-emails

I am reaching out to the community for a help. One of the public facing website we are developing,  will take an anticipated load of 2 million emails per peak hour. In order to perform load testing, I was looking to utilize API calls to create email inboxes.

I have came across some email providers like MailSlurp or Mailinator where we can use email inboxes but do you know if there are any additional providers where we can create that volume of email inboxes? Our company has security concerns on both MailSlurp and Mailinator. Preferably free of cost but with cost will also work.

Comment: Are you sending 2 million emails per hour or receiving them. If you're sending them, you could use a project like mailcatcher to collect them. If you're receiving them, You could run a separate nodemailer application to spam your website.

Comment: @CharlesBamford, thank you for the idea. I think mailcatcher should solve my problem. So our application will send email to 2 million emails per hour but it will be unique email addresses. Let me give it a try to see if I can create 2 million inboxes.